# Joining a table with itself: current month compared to previous month

Tags: mysql, join

I have an order table where I have date, orders, customers. I want to retain all these information but have them grouped by year and month and customer.

The final result must have these columns: year, month, customer, this month orders count and previous month orders count.

How can i do that?

This far i have done the first table with current month performance:

```
SELECT year
     , month
     , customerId
     , count(orderId)
  from order o 
 group 
    by year
     , month
     , customerId
```

Now I want to have near the count(orderId) the count of the previous month: For example in september i want to see the order count in september and the order count in august (and so on).

I have to join the table on itself but i'm wondering how to handle the month problem when the year changes...any suggestion?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And note that order is a reserved word in MySQL, rendering it a poor choice as a table/column identifier.

Comment: Year and month are names of functions which is also not a good thing to do.  You should have something like an OrderDate column as DateTime / Timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still early on in your development, I would take a look at these 3 document pages at a first-shot basis so you can AVOID naming tables and/or columns things that would be considered reserved keywords in the language, or confusion between function names in your final data.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-function-reference.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-data-definition-statements.html

I would suggest that, if you can, change your order table and get rid of year/month columns and put an OrderDate field that is a datetime data type.  This way, it can be sorted easier, yet you can still break out the individual parts of year, month, day, etc. as needed.  You can also have the order date as part of an index to optimize querying.

Next, your date basis.  I will offer two answers, one with your existing data, one based on a better date/time data type field so you can see the simplified difference.  I will apply a sum( case/when ) to get your respective counts per month.  You could even do for total sales if that value is also on the order table.

Because of your column names being the same as function names, I will be prefixing them with the ALIAS name of the table to prevent ambiguity.

```
SELECT
     o.customerId,
     sum( case when o.month = 9 then 1 else 0 end ) LastMonthOrders,
     sum( case when o.month = 10 then 1 else 0 end ) ThisMonthOrders
   from 
      order o
   where
          -- it would be harder when dealing with year overlap
          -- such as December 2020 to Jan 2021
          o.year = 2020
      AND o.month in ( 9, 10 )
   group by 
      o.customerId
```

This will give you one row per customer and the counts per the respective last and current months.  As you can see, very fixed and you would have to change each time the month and/year changed.

Now, lets assume you can change to a date/time column OrderDate in your table instead.  Doing this, I can have my query self-resolve the date ranges AND the sum( case/when ) by using inline MySQL variables.  I can declare them as part of a FROM select statement, then use that as needed.  Again, this sample is based on IF you can change-over to a datetime column on your order table.

```
SELECT 
      o.customerid, 
      sum( case when o.orderDate < @beginOfMonth 
                then 1 else 0 end ) PriorMonthCount,
      sum( case when o.orderDate >= @beginOfMonth 
                then 1 else 0 end ) ThisMonthCount,
      count( * ) TotalOrders
   FROM 
      ( select @myToday := date(curdate()),
               @beginOfMonth := date_sub( @myToday, interval dayOfMonth( @myToday ) -1 day ),
               @beginLastMonth := date_sub( @beginOfMonth, interval 1 month ) ) SqlVars,      
      order o
   WHERE 
      o.deliverydate >= @beginLastMonth
   group by 
      o.customerid
```

The first FROM clause is starting by getting whatever the current date IS, ex: Oct 8, 2020 and putting into a variable @myToday.  Then, it is subtracting the day number (less 1) to get to the first of the month. Oct 8 - ( 8 - 1 ) = Oct 1 and storing into variable @beginOfMonth.  Finally taking that date and going back one month to Sep 1 and storing into @beginLastMonth.  So now, I can apply a where clause to >= the beginning of last month without constantly worrying about a year roll-over, nor which month.

Now, this same principle can be applied with your original query, but would still as you will see is still a bit messy.

```
SELECT
     o.customerId,
     sum( case when o.month = @PriorMonth then 1 else 0 end ) LastMonthOrders,
     sum( case when o.month = @CurrentMonth then 1 else 0 end ) ThisMonthOrders
   from 
      ( select @myToday := date(curdate()),
               @beginOfMonth := date_sub( @myToday, interval dayOfMonth( @myToday ) -1 day ),
               @beginLastMonth := date_sub( @beginOfMonth, interval 1 month ),
               @CurrentYear := year( @beginOfMonth )
               @CurrentMonth := month( @beginOfMonth ),
               @PriorYear := year( @beginLastMonth)
               @PriorMonth := month( @beginLastMonth )  ) SqlVars,      
      order o
   where
          -- it would be harder when dealing with year overlap
          -- such as December 2020 to Jan 2021
          ( o.year = @CurrentYear AND o.month = @CurrentMonth )
      OR  ( o.year = @PriorYear AND o.month = @PriorMonth )
   group by 
      o.customerId
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have an `orders` table with at least the following columns:

```
create table orders (
  order_id int primary key,
  date_order date,
  customer_id int,
  ...
);
```

(please be careful about reserved words). If you want to calculate the number of orders per month you can just use a group by query:

```
select year(date_order), month(date_order), count(*)
from orders
group by year(date_order), month(date_order)
order by 1,2
```

since order_id is the primary key, you could also use this aggregate function `count(distinct order_id)`.

To compare the number of orders in the current month, with the number of orders in the previous month you have to join the table with itself. You could use some date functions to get the first day of the month:

```
date_order - interval day(date_order)-1 day
```

and join in with the records of the previous month:

```
date_order - interval day(date_order)-1 day + interval 1 month
```

(this will work only if `date_order` is of type `date` and not `datetime`, and will automatically handle the correct month when the year changes). The resulting query could be:

```
select
  year(o.date_order),
  month(o.date_order),
  count(distinct o.order_id) as num_orders,
  count(distinct op.order_id) as prev_month_orders
from
  orders o left join orders op
  on
    o.date_order - interval day(o.date_order)-1 day =
    op.date_order - interval day(op.date_order)-1 day + interval 1 month
group by
  year(o.date_order),
  month(o.date_order)
```

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ceb03b/1).